# display:block-inline not working properly

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have set the width of colums to 25% but still the boxes are not appearing in a single line:

[image: image link]

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please add some code samples of what you have tried so far .. instead of just image of the desired result.

Comment: Also paste your full html code

Comment: @Rishabh, Welcome to stackOverflow, If any answer helps you [vote it up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow), If the answer is what you looking for mark it as [Correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the future readers. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I see you have a right border like 1px, by default, your width does not count that as width, therefore, your true width is 25% + 1px. That's why one row only fit 3 boxes.

You need to add: `box-sizing: border-box;` so the 25% width count border as well, then your true width for each box is 25% now. Fit 4 in one row.

> ### box-sizing
>
> REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing?v=example

Example:

```css
span {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  background: lightgray;
}


.test2 span {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  background: lightgray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">
<span>111</span><span>222</span><span>333</span><span>444</span>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="test2">
<span>111</span><span>222</span><span>333</span><span>444</span>
</div>
```